# swift even/odd uibezierpath with line

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a rectangle and I want to cut it out by a line.
I can cut it out by another rectangle etc.. but not with a line.
I set the linewidth on 20 and use the exact same code as I do always but I really can't figure out how to do it with a line.

Here is my code:

```
    let total = CALayer()
    total.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let path1 = UIBezierPath(rect: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 100))
    path2.lineWidth = 20

    path1.append(path2)
    path1.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    let bgLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    bgLayer.path = path1.cgPath
    bgLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    bgLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    total.addSublayer(bgLayer)

    imageview.layer.mask = total
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you want to achieve? The question is unclear.

Comment: I've updated the question.